# ContextMenu Icons not displaying

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, contextmenu

I have some images that I use as icons for `ContextMenu` Items:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="DeleteIco" Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProject.myControl;component/Resources/Delete.ico" Width="16" Height="16"/>
    ...
    <ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu1">
        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Icon="{StaticResource DeleteIco}"/>
    </ContextMenu>

    <ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu2">
        <MenuItem Header="Delete me" Icon="{StaticResource DeleteIco}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
<UserControl.Resources>
```

Sometimes the first menu miss the icon, sometimes the second... why? I don't do anything on the icons in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created an `Image` control, and tried to put it twice in the visual tree. Since all controls can only have one parent your `Image` got disconnected. Thus using it a second time, the first will be disconnected, resulting in your missing icon.

You can resolve this, by not adding the `Image`, but the `ImageSource` instead to your resources:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="DeleteIco" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/MyProject.myControl;component/Resources/Delete.ico" />
```

Your menu has to change a bit for it to work though:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu1">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete">
         <MenuItem.Icon>
              <Image Source="{StaticResource DeleteIco}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
         </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>

<ContextMenu x:Key="MyMenu2">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete me">
         <MenuItem.Icon>
              <Image Source="{StaticResource DeleteIco}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
         </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

**Update:**

You can also use styles to set some basic properties of the `Image` for you

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
</Style>
```

Or use a Style for `MenuItem` to set the `Icon` each time.

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="DeleteMenuIcon">
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
             <Image Source="{StaticResource DeleteIco}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the MenuItem:

```
<MenuItem Header="Delete me" Style="{StaticResource DeleteMenuIcon}" />
```

Comment: seems to be clear... so, any way do not repeat the <MenuItem.Icon>...</> Width="16" Height="16" node?

Comment: Styles.. Use a style to set the icon for you.. Lemme update my answer ;)

Comment: this is more clrear... however, forced to use <menuItem.Icon/> instead of Icon="" :)

Comment: Yes, correct.. You can also use a style to set the icon for you using a named style, and set it on the MenuItem.

Comment: your style does not save me to repeat the same code for the same image. If I have 10 menus with the delete icon, I need to write 10 styles just for that icon?

Comment: No, one style to rule them all.. just repeat the `Style="{StaticResource DeleteMenuIcon}"` on the MenuItem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but the marked solution didn't solve it for me. What *did* solve it was setting [`x:Shared="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) on the `Image` resource:

```
<Image x:Key="DeleteIco" 
       x:Shared="False"
       Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProject.myControl;component/Resources/Delete.ico"
       Width="16" Height="16"/>
```

As @Arcturus correctly mentioned, you're currently setting the same image control as a child for multiple controls, which causes it to be detached from the previous control each time, and then only be set for the last control. Setting `x:Shared="False"` will cause a new `Image` control to be created each time the resource is requested, thus solving the problem.

One thing to note is that the `x:Shared` attribute cannot be set everywhere, so make sure you use it where it's actually applicable (from the above article):

> In WPF, x:Shared is only valid under the following conditions:
>
> - The ResourceDictionary that contains the items with x:Shared must be
>     compiled. The ResourceDictionary cannot be within loose XAML or used
>     for themes.
> - The ResourceDictionary that contains the items must not be
>     nested within another ResourceDictionary. For example, you cannot use
>     x:Shared for items in a ResourceDictionary that is within a Style that
>     is already a ResourceDictionary item.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the `x:Shared`. The intellisense could not even show it, but as soon as I added this, it worked!